# How to get file path , When uploading a file to server?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-file

I am developing a simple application in which user can upload his document to server. I am able to upload file to server but the problem i am getting is , when i am selecting file from this location `/storage/sdcard/sample.txt` ,i am able to upload but when i am selecting the file from different location the file is not uploading and in logcat i am getting this location `/storage/sdcard/demo.docx`, "demo.docx" is file which i selected from different location

MyLogcat

```
04-20 18:31:45.990 1404-2066/? W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
04-20 18:31:45.995 1404-1432/? W/IntentResolver: resolveIntent: multiple matches, only some with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
04-20 18:31:45.995 1404-1432/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=*/* cmp=com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity} from uid 10217 on display 0
04-20 18:31:45.997 1404-1432/? V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{12932f9c token=Token{1cf9a30f ActivityRecord{1b7ac06e u0 com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity t2252}}} to stack=1 task=2252 at 1
04-20 18:31:46.081 1404-4882/? V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{1596757a u0 com.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity} at 3 of 6 (after Window{e2669c0 u0 org.pitechnologies.pi_technologies1/org.pitechnologies.pi_technologies1.FilePik})
04-20 18:31:46.124 2844-2862/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-20 18:31:46.125 2844-2862/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa5e0b5a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-20 18:31:46.202 1404-1431/? W/IntentResolver: resolveIntent: multiple matches, only some with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
04-20 18:31:46.210 1404-1559/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity: +185ms
04-20 18:31:46.240 5054-5069/? D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb41c6b80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb43da890
04-20 18:31:46.259 2844-2844/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
04-20 18:31:46.259 2844-2844/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.android.music: Resource ID #0x0
04-20 18:31:46.285 2844-2844/? D/Documents: Current stack: 
04-20 18:31:46.285 2844-2844/? D/Documents:  * Root{authority=com.android.providers.downloads.documents, rootId=downloads, title=Downloads}
04-20 18:31:46.285 2844-2844/? D/Documents:  +-- Document{docId=downloads, name=null}
04-20 18:31:46.292 2844-4869/? D/Documents: userMode=0, userSortOrder=0 --> mode=1, sortOrder=2
04-20 18:31:46.300 2844-2844/? W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
04-20 18:31:46.300 2844-2844/? W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.android.music: Resource ID #0x0
04-20 18:31:46.336 2844-4869/? W/Documents: Failed to load thumbnail for content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
04-20 18:31:48.897 1404-2066/? W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
04-20 18:31:48.908 2844-2844/? D/Documents: onFinished() [content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/4]
04-20 18:31:48.939 5054-5054/? I/tagconvertstr-->: [demo.docx]
04-20 18:31:48.963 5054-5069/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-20 18:31:48.963 5054-5069/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa50e52e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-20 18:31:49.390 2844-2844/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3193(245KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 30% free, 1142KB/1654KB, paused 9.317ms total 17.764ms
04-20 18:31:49.470 2844-2844/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 595(68KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 1033KB/1545KB, paused 1.860ms total 24.646ms
04-20 18:31:49.490 2844-2844/? I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 1033KB/1545KB, paused 1.842ms total 19.211ms
04-20 18:31:49.493 2844-2844/? E/StrictMode: class com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity; instances=2; limit=1
                                             android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity; instances=2; limit=1
                                                 at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
04-20 18:31:49.984 2094-2108/? I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 32252(1965KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 21% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 10.375ms total 29.108ms
04-20 18:31:50.787 1404-2066/? W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard/demo.docx: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:78)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.james.mime4j.message.MessageWriter.writeBody(MessageWriter.java:76)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.doWriteTo(HttpMultipart.java:202)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo(HttpMultipart.java:223)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:179)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:102)
04-20 18:31:50.806 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:167)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:277)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:242)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:433)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.pitechnologies.pi_technologies1.FilePik$PostDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(FilePik.java:128)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at org.pitechnologies.pi_technologies1.FilePik$PostDataAsyncTask.doInBackground(FilePik.java:107)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-20 18:31:50.807 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
04-20 18:31:50.808 5054-5089/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
04-20 18:31:50.808 5054-5089/? W/System.err:    ... 23 more
```

MainActivity

```
public class FilePik extends Activity {
Button b1,b2;
String displayName;
TextView txt_file_name_1;

private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filepik);
    txt_file_name_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textt);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new PostDataAsyncTask().execute();

        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showFileChooser();

        }
    });

}
private void showFileChooser() {


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK  ) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String uriString = uri.toString();
                File myFile = new File(uriString);
                displayName = null;

                if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {

                        cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

                            Log.i("tagconvertstr-->", "[" + displayName + "]");
                        }
                    } finally {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                    displayName = myFile.getName();

                    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "[" + displayName + "]");
                }

                txt_file_name_1.setText(displayName);

            }

          //  txt_file_name_1.setText(displayName);
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://*****/*****/newfile.php");

            File file1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File myDir = new File(file1, displayName);
            FileBody fileBody1 = new FileBody(myDir);
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("file1", fileBody1);




            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if (resEntity != null) {
                final String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)
                        .trim();


            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Log.e("", "RESULT : " + result);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: where is demo.docx located in your device?

Comment: Demo.docx is located inside internal memory

Answer (score 0):

You should use the file's path and not his name.Instead of

```
displayName = myFile.getName();
```

Use `getPath()` here:

```
else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {

    displayName = myFile.getPath();

    Log.i("tagconvertstr", "[" + displayName + "]");
}
```

Comment: I am still not getting path

Comment: I can't see any place where you're passing the path to your asyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the file in External SD card whereas it is in Internal Storage. Use the following code to get the file from Internal Storage :

```
      String filepath="directory containing file ";
      ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
      File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      File myInternalFile = new File(directory , filename);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set specific mime Type in your case Documnent Type would work

Comment: He is getting FileNotFoundException witch has nothing to do with Content-Type !